# redirect_to on new page in rails_admin's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm just starting to learn gem 'rails_admin' and don't understand much yet.
I have code in action

for example

```
...
register_instance_option :controller do
 proc do
   url = object.url

   redirect_to url, allow_other_host: true
end
...
```

How do I open this link in a new tab in rails_admin
Sorry for my English, it's not native.

I tried to include js but it doesn't work in my application. Maybe there is some function in rails_admin

Comment: Is this for a new action? or are you overriding an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Due to insufficient knowledge of rails_admin still found a solution. Added a function

```
register_instance_option :link_target do
 "_blank"
end
```